# c++ File transfer

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a problem sending a file from client to server. When I send text files it's alright. But when I try to send a binary file, I recieve only one part of file or the app crashes. I'd love some code, that works fine for binary transfer. I use WinSock and I have `SOCKET` pointing at server and `SOCKET` pointing at client. I already tried almost everything, please help a bit.
Thanx for any replies.

EDIT:
I have no source actualy. I need help what changes in sending exe files than in sendig txt. Conversion? I open it as bin, but it doesnt help.

EDIT2:
@thkala:
It was very specific. I think I did all 3 possible errors, i used getline() and terminated on 0 byte, so it may be this. If not getline(), what to use? Im open at any liblary to use files, I use fstream for now.

Comment: The community can help you debug your code (if you provide it). If you are only looking for code search Google, you will find plenty.

Comment: Please post some code so that others could suggest fixes to it. If you have code that transfers text files OK, perhaps we could spot the problem that prevents you from sending binaries.

Comment: Try flushing the buffer after you're done sending everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few significant differences between text and binary files, that may or may not trip you up:

- Text files typically have *lines*, delimited by line terminators. Using line-oriented functions for binary files can fail in various interesting ways.
- As a follow-up to the previous point, there is *no guarantee* that a binary file will ever contain even a single line terminator. This difference tends to break code that unwittingly assumes that a line cannot be longer than X characters, then goes on to allocate memory based on that assumption, before slurping-in the whole input. No matter how large X may be, there will always be a file that will be bigger. BTW, such code will also typically break on machine-generated text files with very long lines.
- Text files are usually assumed to not contain zero bytes, while binary files very often do. Since the zero byte is the termination indicator for C-style strings, binary content tends to be mangled when processed by text-oriented functions. Even the wide-character versions of the various functions will break, since they only expect zero bytes in specific locations.

Unless you post some of your code, it is not really possible to provide more specific help than this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fread()`, `ReadFile()` or similar function to read a chunk of data from the file into a memory buffer, `send()` the buffer over the socket, then repeat as needed until the entire file has been read.  If you don't mind using Microsoft-specific functionality, then you can alternatively open the file with `CreateFile()` and then use `TransmitFile()` to have WinSock send the file over the socket for you so you don't have to read it manually.